# Character diff/annotation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, diff

I have a set of string representing the history of a document. Each string is the whole document - there has not yet been any diff analysis.

I need a relatively efficient algorithm to allow me to annotate substrings of the document with the version they came from.

For example, if the document history was like this:

```
Rev1: The quiet fox
Rev2: The quiet brown fox
Rev3: The quick brown fox
```

The algorithm would give:

```
The quick brown fox
1111111331222222111
```

i.e. "The qui" was added in revision 1, "ck" was added in revision 3, " " was added in revision 1, "brown " was added in revision 2 and finally "fox" was added in revision 1.

Comment: Are the documents plain-text?

Comment: Yes, they're plain-text. In real life each document is a plain-text string of ~500-2000 characters with ~5-200 revisions.

Comment: Could you upload or publish a sample document zip file somewhere? I have an implementation (I'll add the answer below) that I'd like to run against it. I managed to reproduce your exact example but I'd like to see performance on a typical dataset.

Comment: What happens when Rev4 is "The quick brown fox and black fox" and Rev5 is "The quiet fox"?

Comment: Did you find what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a class library that can do this easily, though I don't know how well it performs performance-wise with large or many such revisions.

The library is here: [DiffLib on CodePlex](http://difflib.codeplex.com/) (you can also install it through NuGet.)

The script for your example in the question is here (you can run this in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net/) if you add a reference to the DiffLib assembly):

```
void Main()
{
    var revs = new string[]
    {
        "The quiet fox",
        "The quiet brown fox",
        "The quick brown fox",
        "The quick brown fox.",
        "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.",
        "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy cat.",
        "The Quick Brown Fox jumped over the Lazy Cat.",
    };

    string current = revs[0];
    List<int> owner = new List<int>();
    foreach (char c in current)
        owner.Add(1); // owner 1 owns entire string

    Action<int> dumpRev = delegate(int rev)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("rev " + rev);
        Debug.WriteLine(current);
        Debug.WriteLine(new string(owner.Select(i => (char)(48 + i)).ToArray()));
        Debug.WriteLine("");
    };
    dumpRev(0);

    for (int index = 1; index < revs.Length; index++)
    {
        int ownerId = index + 1;
        var diff = new DiffLib.Diff<char>(current, revs[index]).ToArray();
        int position = 0;
        foreach (var part in diff)
        {
            if (part.Equal)
                position += part.Length1;
            else
            {
                // get rid of old owner for the part that was
                // removed or replaced
                for (int index2 = 0; index2 < part.Length1; index2++)
                    owner.RemoveAt(position);

                // insert new owner for the part that was
                // added or did replace the old text
                for (int index2 = 0; index2 < part.Length2; index2++)
                    owner.Insert(position, ownerId);
                position += part.Length2;
            }
        }
        current = revs[index];
        dumpRev(index);
    }
}
```

The output:

```
rev 0
The quiet fox
1111111111111

rev 1
The quiet brown fox
1111111111222222111

rev 2
The quick brown fox
1111111331222222111

rev 3
The quick brown fox.
11111113312222221114

rev 4
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
111111133122222211155555555555555555555555554

rev 5
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy cat.
111111133122222211155555555555555555555556664

rev 6
The Quick Brown Fox jumped over the Lazy Cat.
111171133172222271155555555555555555755557664
```

Comment: Note that this is the brute-force method, there are probably plenty of optimizations to do here. For instance, for larger documents I would probably use a linked list for the owner id's to avoid shuffling around the list contents, or change the two loops there to avoid this altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [Myers diff algorithm as implemented by Google](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/).  It's fairly fast and has implementations in lots of languages, and you can provide timeout values to keep it from wasting too much time searching for complicated differences.

The output should be pretty trivially converted to the sort of scoring that you want (credit assignment patch by patch).

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't your "history" format already provide that information? If so, then its just a matter of displaying it. The most efficient method would depend on the format your history is stored in, of course, so nobody here can really provide that for you without knowing that format.

It should be noted that if you are sending the output to some kind of display device (eg: the screen), then generally your algorithim would have to be *really* dumb to slow things down much more than the display device will already be slowing things down.

Comment: The "history" format is just an ordered set of what the document contents were in that particular revision. So from the example given, the history is `["The quiet fox", "The quiet brown fox", " The quick brown fox"]`. This doesn't easily expose the information that the 'f' of 'fox' in the latest revision was added in the first revision, while the 'b' of brown was added in the second.

Comment: @ICR - So it doesn't just store diffs to save space? That's a pretty typical setup for a real-world revision history system.

Comment: The original probably does. Unfortunately I can only query for the document at a specific revision. I cannot change this.

Comment: @ICR - I find it hard to believe that it would do that, and then not provide you some way to get a "version diff" between two versions, since that would actually be *less work for it* than pulling out the most recent version.